# Why is this AJAX function not working properly?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have written a simple application that displays a list of candidates for a job, then, upon clicking a hire button, should alter a database to reflect the newly hired candidate and display the rest as unhired.  However, the function is not working properly.  The problem I am having is the AJAX function never seems to provide a response, and I cannot figure out why.  The database is also not getting updated.  My files are below.

The line `document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.readyState+" "+xmlhttp.status+"<br>";` is updating a div at the bottom of my html page, showing that the the `readyState` is 4 and the `status` is 200, which should mean that the AJAX function returned properly, but the `echo`'d response is not being displayed.  Even when I remove all code from the new_hire.php file and simply make the file `echo "hello";`, nothing is returned in the `responseText`.

resumes.php:

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function new_hire(name){
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.readyState+" "+xmlhttp.status+"<br>";

    //this line, when removed, does not change anything. I left it in for debugging purposes.
    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;

    if (xmlhttp.readyState=4 && xmlhttp.status=200){

      var others = xmlhttp.responseText.split("|");

      for (i=0;i<others.length;i++){
        tag = others[i].replace(" ","_");

        document.getElementById(tag).innerHTML="";
      }
    } 
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","new_hire.php",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("hiree="+name.replace(" ","%20")+"&position=Salespeople");

  var name_tag = name.replace(" ","_");

  document.getElementById(name_tag).innerHTML="(Current Employee)<br>";
}
</script>

</head>

...

</html>
```

new_hire.php (AJAX response file):

```
<?php

$hiree = $_POST['hiree'];
$pos = $_POST['position'];


$con = mysql_connect("host.name","user","pass") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);

$clear = mysql_query("UPDATE $pos SET employed=false WHERE 1=1;");
mysql_fetch_array($clear);

$reset = mysql_query("UPDATE $pos SET employed=true WHERE Name='$hiree';");
mysql_fetch_array($reset);

$people = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM $pos WHERE employed=false;");
$array = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($people)){
    array_push($array,$row['Name']);
}

mysql_close($con);

$response = join("|",$array);
echo $response;

?>
```

Comment: You can not read the responseText before readystate 4.

Comment: I understand that, but when I remove the line that attempts to do this, there is no change.  There must be something else that is wrong.

Comment: What happens if you put the responseText line inside the "if (xmlhttp.readyState=4 && xmlhttp.status=200){" block?

Comment: @ZackMacomber there is still no response text returned.  I can only imagine that I am making a mistake with the HTTP request somewhere, as the response text is empty even when the new_hire.php file contains nothing but a single `echo "hello world!"`

Comment: I was looking at an ajax post request example and "encodeURIComponent" was used on the parameters passed in the send portion.  http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost2.shtml is the link - specifically the Ajax POST request portion.  You might need to encode those parms in order for them to be recognized correctly in new_hire.php.

Comment: What are the status codes returned? Have use used a tool like Firebug, Fiddler, or Charles to see what is being returned from the server?

Comment: The status codes are all 200s.

Comment: Please note that your `if` statement is not using the comparison operator `==` but rather the assignment operator `=` so you are using: `if (xmlhttp.readyState=4 && xmlhttp.status=200)` instead of `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)`

Comment: @Yaniro. Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your if statement is not using the comparison operator `==` but rather the assignment operator `=` so you are using: `if (xmlhttp.readyState=4 && xmlhttp.status=200)` instead of `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)`